# Removing requirement jQuery Minimum Image dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-validate

I have a form where the user inputs an image and then submits. I am using the jQuery validator plugin to validate if the image is really an image, the file size of the image, and the dimensions of the image. The user does not have to upload an image, but if they do, then the image will be undergoing these rules. I have also put in a cropping plugin. This plugin (crobox) crops the image based on what the user wants cropped. Currently, the form works correctly with the validation rules. However, the user is not required to submit an image, but the validator tells the user that the user should submit an image that is at least 600px x 360px even when the user did not upload anything. How do I make it so that the validator does not show an error when the user does not want to upload an image? Here's my **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujnnaL8z/)**

**HTML**

```
<form class="properties_form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="imageGroup">
    <input class="image_upload" name="image_upload" type="file">
    <div class="imgBox">

    </div>
  </div>
  <input class="finish_btn" type="submit">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".properties_form").validate({
  errorElement: 'div',
  rules: {

    image_upload: {
      extension: "jpg|png|jpeg|JPG|PNG|JPEG",
      filesize: 100000,
      minImageSize: {
        width: 600,
        height: 360
      }
    },
  },


  messages: {
    image_upload: {
      extension: "We only accept .jpg and .png images.",
      minImageSize: "Your image must be at least 600px by 360px.",
      filesize: "Your image size should not exceed 100KB"
    },
  },

});


var $form = $('.properties_form'),
  $finish_btn = $form.find('finish_btn');
$form.find('.image_upload').change(function() {
  var $image_upload = $(this),
    $imgBox = $image_upload.closest('.imageGroup').find('.imgBox');

  $image_upload.removeData('imageSize');
  $imgBox.hide().empty();

  var file = this.files[0];

  if (file.type.match(/image\/.*/)) {
    $finish_btn.attr('disabled', true);

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
      var $img = $('<img />').attr({
        src: reader.result
      });

      $img.on('load', function() {
        $imgBox.append($img).show();

        $image_upload.data('imageSize', {
          width: $img.width(),
          height: $img.height()
        });

        $img.css({
          display: "none"
        });

        $finish_btn.attr('disabled', false);

        validator.element($image_upload);
      });
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    validator.element($image_upload);
  }
});


$(function() {

  $(".image_upload").on('change', function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var $img = $('<img />').attr({
        src: reader.result
      });

      $img.on('load', function() {
        $img.cropbox({
          width: 650,
          height: 360
        }).on('cropbox', function(event, results, img) {

        });
      });

      $('.imgBox').append($img);

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});

$.validator.addMethod('minImageSize', function(value, element, minSize) {
  var imageSize = $(element).data('imageSize');
  return (imageSize) && (imageSize.width >= minSize.width) && (imageSize.height >= minSize.height);
}, function(minSize, element) {
  return ($(element).data('imageSize')) ? ("Your image's size must be at least " + minSize.width + "px by " + minSize.height + "px") : "Selected file is not an image.";
});

$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
  return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
}, 'File size must be less than {0}');
```

Answer (score 0):

> the validator tells the user that the user should submit an image that is at least 600px x 360px even when the user did not upload anything

That's because you forgot to make your `minImageSize` rule *optional*.

```
return this.optional(element) || .....
```

Without this part, the rule will always be evaluated on empty fields.  You'll need to use `this.optional(element)` to check if the element is "optional"...

```
$.validator.addMethod('minImageSize', function(value, element, minSize) {
    var imageSize = $(element).data('imageSize');
    return this.optional(element) || ((imageSize) && (imageSize.width >= minSize.width) && (imageSize.height >= minSize.height));
}, function(minSize, element) {
    return ($(element).data('imageSize')) ? ("Your image's size must be at least " + minSize.width + "px by " + minSize.height + "px") : "Selected file is not an image.";
});
```